# trying to convert VBA database declarations to C#

Tags: c#, sql, vba

I'm trying to convert the following code from VBA to C# in the **simplest** way possible, could you please help me:

```vb
Dim database As DAO.Database
Dim result As DAO.Recordset
```

The problem is I'm now using an SQL database instead of DAO and I can't seem to make it work in a similar easy way.
Is there a similar way to declare an SQL database and Recordset in C#?

Comment: Post what you've already tried.  "i can't seem to make it work in a similar easy way" is not helpful.

Comment: `I'm now using an SQL database instead of DAO` - that makes no sense. DAO is a tool that lets one use an SQL database. In any case converting that code will give you nothing because you will have to convert everything else too.

Comment: first off, thanks for your help GSerg. the problem is the VBA code is refering to an old access database and i want to use a sql database as my source.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 public void OpenConnection(SqlConnection DBConnection)
        {
            try
            {       
                    DBConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server = " + Server + "; Database = " + DataBase + "; User ID = Username; Password = Password; Trusted_Connection = False;Max Pool Size=1000";


                    DBConnection.Open();
                    bIsConnected = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }


        public void FillDataTable(DataTable dataTable, SqlConnection DBConnection, ref string sql)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, DBConnection);

            try
            {
                da.Fill(dataTable);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(sql, ex);
            }
        }

        public static MY_TB.MY_TBDataTable GetMyTB()
        {
            try
            {
                string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM MY_TB");

                SqlConnection sql = OpenConnection(sql);
                MY_TB tb = new MY_TB();
                db.FillDataTable(tb._MY_TB, ref sql);

                return tb._MY_TB;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally { mb.db.CloseConnection(); }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a poor code example: unnecessary try...catch, not disposing of resources (SqlConnections etc), unnecessary methods (OpenConnection) etc.

Comment: OP asked for "simplest way possible"

Comment: The OP may be asking "How do I use DAO with C#?"

Comment: OP says: "using an sql database instead of DAO"

Comment: yeah i don't want to use DAO, i want to use SQL but in a similar way.

i think what i want to know is if it's possible to declare a sql database (and a recordset) as a variable (so i can use it in my code as a variable)?

Comment: `OP asked for "simplest way possible"` - incorrect <> simplest.